# How to calculate $\partial_i (\gamma \space \partial_i \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}u \bigg))$?

Tags: differential-equations

I tried calculating the following, but Mathematica seemed to spit out a long expression that couldn't be even simplified much.

So, how to calculate $$\partial_i (\gamma \space \partial_i \bigg( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}u \bigg))$$?

Where $\gamma, u$ are twice-differentiable multivariable functions.

Input:

```
D[g[x]*D[g[x]^(-1/2)*u[x], x], x]
```

Output:

```
Derivative[1][g][x]*
     (-((u[x]*Derivative[1][g][x])/
             (2*g[x]^(3/2))) + 
        Derivative[1][u][x]/
          Sqrt[g[x]]) + 
   g[x]*((3*u[x]*Derivative[1][g][x]^
               2)/(4*g[x]^(5/2)) - 
        (Derivative[1][g][x]*
             Derivative[1][u][x])/
          g[x]^(3/2) - 
        (u[x]*Derivative[2][g][x])/
          (2*g[x]^(3/2)) + 
        Derivative[2][u][x]/Sqrt[g[x]])
```

For source have a look at:

[users.jyu.fi/~salomi/lecturenotes/calderon_lectures.pdf](http://users.jyu.fi/~salomi/lecturenotes/calderon_lectures.pdf) page 16

Comment: Please paste code for $\gamma$ and $u$... otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Let's see your function.  Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: HEY!!!  You simply *MUST* post `g[x_]:= ...`, otherwise we cannot help you.  Why do you refuse to do this when we're trying to help you?  (Over and out.)

Comment: `D[g[x]*D[g[x]^(-1/2)*u[x], x], x] // Simplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon With this I get: `(-u[x] (Derivative[1][g][x]^2 - 2 g[x] (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) - 
 4 g[x]^2 (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x])/(4 g[x]^(3/2))`. Which still doesn't look right.

Comment: 1) Convert your expressions to `InputForm` prior to copy & paste. 2) What about the output doesn't look right? What output are you expecting and why?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt) instead of [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D):

```
res = Sum[Dt[\[Gamma] Dt[1/Sqrt[\[Gamma]] u, i], i], {i, {x, y, z}}] //Simplify;
res //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{4 \gamma ^2 \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-2 \gamma  u \frac{d^2\gamma }{dx^2}+u \left(\frac{d\gamma }{dx}\right)^2+4 \gamma ^2 \frac{d^2u}{dy^2}-2 \gamma  u
>    \frac{d^2\gamma }{dy^2}+u \left(\frac{d\gamma }{dy}\right)^2+4 \gamma ^2 \frac{d^2u}{dz^2}-2 \gamma  u \frac{d^2\gamma }{dz^2}+u \left(\frac{d\gamma
>    }{dz}\right)^2}{4 \gamma ^{3/2}}$

Answer (score 1):

If your functions $g$ and $u$ eat vectors (and not a sequence of scalar arguments), you can achieve your goal this way:

```
n = 3;
xx = Quiet[Table[x[[i]], {i, 1, n}]];
res = Tr[D[g[xx] D[u[xx]/Sqrt[g[xx]], {xx, 1}], {xx, 1}]] // Simplify
```

Note that the index $i$ appearing twice in your formula. Usually, this is often meant to be summed up (a.k.a. Einstein notation). That's why the trace appears.

As an alternative, you can also use the `Grad` and `Div` operators (with respect to the Euclidean metric).

```
res = Div[g[xx] Grad[u[xx]/Sqrt[g[xx]], xx], xx] // Simplify
```

**Side remark**

Yes, the resulting expressions do not look to nice. That's why one should avoid index notation.

Comment: Have a look at http://users.jyu.fi/~salomi/lecturenotes/calderon_lectures.pdf page 16.

Answer (score 0):

```
(expr1 = D[g[x]^(-1/2)*u[x], x]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(expr2 = D[g[x]*expr1, x]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(expr3 = expr2 // Expand) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(expr4 = expr3 // Simplify) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
expr2 == expr3 == expr4 == 
  D[g[x]*D[g[x]^(-1/2)*u[x], x], x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```